# How can an undergrad absolutely impress Research Professor during a research internship?

Tags: phd, research-process, undergraduate, internship, science

I have been accepted for a research position in a very renowned Medical Professor's research group over the summer. The internship starts after 5 months so I have enough time to prepare to perform extremely well and impress the Professor. I would appreciate if you provide me some valuable tips and advice. Thanks!

Comment: Do a good job :-) And, frankly, don't try to impress the prof. Try to impress yourself, and, that's the tougher part if you do it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is straight-forward.

- Gain enough knowledge of what your research group is progressing on
- Develop skill-sets that would aid to to work in the group

Better yet, contact the professor and ask if there is anything you could do get *prepared* for the research internship. This would not only portray your enthusiasm and dedication, it would give you a clearer idea on what exactly to improve.

Comment: done! but does that mean i'll no longer get more answers to my question?

Comment: @usmleshah Not really, there are many instances where questions get answers even after acceptance. But it does seem unlikely in your case as there are two outstanding close votes to your question. Others believe that it is not *generalizable* (though I don't vouch for that reason). You may refer [this post](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1736/revisiting-custom-close-reasons) for more details.

Comment: @usmleshah But you need not to worry much since even when closed, your post will still be open for view and accessible to the public and can still receive upvotes (and even become famous). [This link](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55612/why-do-people-in-academia-tend-to-write-their-email-address-with-dot-at) is a good example.

Answer (score 3):

Do exactly the opposite. Get all your *other* stuff done before you start the internship. You will need a clean head there, so make a 200% effort to clean your mind before the internship starts. During an internship, do only the internship. Nothing else. Really *nothing* else.